# Java- why is if() block inside of while() statement executed?

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

I would need explanation, why is `if()` block inside of `while()` statement executed.It's said that:  ***The while statement evaluates expression, which must return a boolean value. If the expression evaluates to true, the while statement executes the statement(s) in the while block.*** So please, take a look at this code:

```
class test{
static int x;

public static void main(String args[]){
    while(x!=5){
        x=x+1;
        if(x==5)
            System.out.println("I'm 5 now!");
    }
  }
}
```

Once variable x gains amout of 5, shouldn't be `(x!=5)` considered as false? So how can be if block executed? Basically it seems like it returns *true* boolean value for expression **5!=5**.

Thank you for explanation!

Comment: x = 4, the next line adds 1 to x, so x would = 5 at time of if statement

Comment: Use `+=` or `++` rather than `x = x + 1`. So `x++`.

Comment: Learn more about while statement. Condition in while is evaluated only before body of while is executed (and after while body gets executed) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Comment: If you had debugged the code (it smells like homework) you would have found the answer yourself ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While loops are known as *pre-condition* loops, meaning they check a condition *before* executing some block of statements.

So when `x` becomes `5` in the body of the loop, the last condition that was actually checked was `x != 4`.

`x != 5` will be checked the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: This should be correct answer. I think @Matt doesn't understand that while condition is not evaluated in body of while

Answer (score 5):

If x == 4 then while is satisfied `x != 5`. Then you increment x `x = x+1`  and have `x == 5`. That's why

Answer (score 3):

When you enter the loop's body and `x == 4`, it proceeds.

Then, you add `1` to the variable.

It's `5` now, so the `if`'s condition is true!

Answer (score 3):

This is because your `x` becomes equal to 5 *after* it enters the loop. On the next iteration the loop stops. You should move `x=x+1` line after the `if` to make it work the way you want

Answer (score 2):

When you enter the loop with `X` equal to 4, it is first incremented to take value 5, therefore satisfying the expression `x == 5`.

But then, at the next iteration, the condition in `while` is not true anymore.

Answer (score 2):

```
  while(x!=5){ // here maximum value accept as true is 4
        x=x+1; // now 4+1 and x =5
        if(x==5) //yes condition satisfied 
            System.out.println("I'm 5 now!"); //so out put will print 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It enters the while loop while x=4 i.e, (4!=5 right??)

and x=x+1 is executed inside the while loop, so x=5; and the next line
inside while loop is   if(x==5) System.out.println("I'm 5 now!");

as value of x is 5 , the execution enters the if condition and we will
get the output  as "I'm 5 now!"

Answer (score 1):

The expression `x == 5` is evaluated to true, because x is changed inside the while loop.

When x equals 4 (which means `x != 5` still evaluates to true), the next line (`x = x + 1`) results in x being 5.